# report with type techreport only has authors in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have a question about biblatex's report of type techreport. I read in the manual that techreport is old, and therefore report is preferred. So I use report, with type techreport, but then my reference only shows the authors or the report. Below is my code:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\author{Nikkie Deelen}
\title{\textbf{DRAFT} Characterizing modules for the \cmsphttu{}}

\usepackage{csquotes}                                                                       % For using biblatex                
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}                                     % New and improved biblatex
\addbibresource{intro.bib}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{sorting=none, maxnames=5, minnames=3, hyperref, backref, backrefstyle=three, abbreviate=false, date=long, urldate=long}

\begin{document}
    This is the techreport that I want to cite \autocite{lumiconcept}
\end{document}
```

And here is my intro.bib file:

```latex
@report{lumiconcept,
    author          = {Herr, W. and Muratori, B.}},
    title           = {Concept of luminosity},
    date            = {2006},
    type            = {techreport},
    url             = {https://cds.cern.ch/record/941318},
    urldate         = {2019-08-19},
    institution     = {{CERN}},
    doi             = {10.5170/CERN-2006-002.361},
}
```

What I see is only this below, and I would like to see the title, and other stuff that is in the bibfile as well, could someone please help me with this?

[image: Biblatex output]

Comment: There is a typo in the `.bib` entry: `author = {Herr, W. and Muratori, B.}},` is has too many closing braces, it should be `author = {Herr, W. and Muratori, B.},`

Comment: I don't think the manual says that `@techreport` shouldn't be used and that you must use `@report` instead. `@techreport` is the same as a `@report` with `type = {techreport},` and thus can save you a tiny but of typing if you want the 'technical report' in the doc.

Comment: Thanks @moewe! But then I still don't understand why it only prints out the authors in the references and not for instance the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the `author` field of the entry

```
@report{lumiconcept,
    author          = {Herr, W. and Muratori, B.}},
    title           = {Concept of luminosity},
    date            = {2006},
    type            = {techreport},
    url             = {https://cds.cern.ch/record/941318},
    urldate         = {2019-08-19},
    institution     = {{CERN}},
    doi             = {10.5170/CERN-2006-002.361},
}
```

The two closing curly braces in the entry mean that the entry is parsed as

```
@report{lumiconcept,
    author          = {Herr, W. and Muratori, B.}
}
```

everything else will be seen as junk characters and will be discarded. Hence you only get the author names and nothing else.

Just remove the superfluous brace to make the entry read

```
@report{lumiconcept,
    author          = {Herr, W. and Muratori, B.},
    title           = {Concept of luminosity},
    date            = {2006},
    type            = {techreport},
    url             = {https://cds.cern.ch/record/941318},
    urldate         = {2019-08-19},
    institution     = {{CERN}},
    doi             = {10.5170/CERN-2006-002.361},
}
```

---

While `@techreport` is listed in the *Type Aliases* section of the `biblatex` manual this doesn't mean you are not allowed to use it any more. The alias type `@techreport` is equivalent to `@report` with `type = {techreport}`, so it would be absolutely fine to give the entry in question as

```
@techreport{lumiconcept,
    author          = {Herr, W. and Muratori, B.},
    title           = {Concept of luminosity},
    date            = {2006},
    url             = {https://cds.cern.ch/record/941318},
    urldate         = {2019-08-19},
    institution     = {{CERN}},
    doi             = {10.5170/CERN-2006-002.361},
}
```

In fact this saves a little bit of typing, so it might actually be preferred.

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborate answer!